# set default value for date in Ui component

Tags: magento2

This is my UI component form

```
 <field name="test[start_date]">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sales_rule</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">33</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">test[start_date]</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

I want to load default value for date. I added a plugin for

```
Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Metadata\ValueProvider
```

this is my code

```
public function aroundGetMetadataValues(
        SalesRuleValueProvider $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        Rule $rule
    ) {
        $result = $proceed($rule);
        $actions = &$result['actions']['children']['simple_action']['arguments']['data']['config']['options'];

        $result['actions']['children']['test[start_date]']['arguments']['data']['config']['value']
            = '2014-09-01';
        return $result;
    }
```

All other input field are working very well. I was able to pre populate it with a value except date. I tried all date format available, Any help on this

Answer (score 5):

you can achieve  this functionality below code.

UI component form in xml file like **custom_form.xml**:

```
<field name="your_field_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">{Vendorname}\{Modulename}\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">End Date</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">89</item>                  
                   <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">your_field_id</item>
                   <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enter the Account Removed Date of Customer(mm/dd/yyyy)</item>

                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Create file In `{Vendorname}\{Modulename}\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input.php`

And add the logic in element **Input.php** file

```
<?php

    namespace {Vendorname}\{Modulename}\Ui\Component\Form\Element;

    class Input extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input
    {
        /**
         * Prepare component configuration
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function prepare()
        {
            parent::prepare();

            $config = $this->getData('config');

            if(isset($config['dataScope']) && $config['dataScope']=='your_field_id'){
                $config['default']= date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 years'));
                $this->setData('config', (array)$config);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please check and let know.

Comment: Thanks alot @ramki, I really appreciate. It works perfectly

Comment: @soladogunilyasAdemuyiwa you're welcome :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try converting the date string to a date object like this:

```
$dateValue = '2011-03-05'
$value = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateValue));
```

And then add it as the value.

Not sure if it works.